# Render elements on the same line, with input element consuming all free space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the icon, the `input` and the `button` to be inline.

The width of the `input` is reduced because of the `display: inline-block`.

I have tried absolute positioning the button and and adding a relative position to the outer div, or floating the input and the button, but nothing has worked so far.

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Here is the structure of my code.

```css
.first {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

i {
  margin-right: 19px;
  color: purple;
}

.third {
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

.fourth {
  float: right !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="first">
  <div clas="second">
    <i class="material-icons">&#xE8B6;</i>
    <div class="third">
      <input type="search" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fourth">
    <button>Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2a04ds2y/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn about flexbox. Keep it really simple:

```css
.first {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

input {
  flex: 1; /* tells input to consume all free space on the line */
}

i {
  margin-right: 19px;
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="first">
  <i class="material-icons">&#xE8B6;</i>
  <input type="search" />
  <button>Click</button>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2a04ds2y/2/)

Comment: Thank you! Since I can't simplify the structure of my code, I ended up doing something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/2a04ds2y/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left` and add `clear: both` div

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fh80vru4/)